# How to convert a REST trigger pathParam to an activity input param

Tags: tibco

I am trying to create a flogo application with a path-paremeterized trigger. The trigger should respond to a call like this:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/trigger/apply
```

In the above example, "apply" is the string that I want to pass into the flows first activity as an input parameter called 'command'.

```
  "handlers": [
    {
      "actionId": "kubectlAction",
      "actionMappings": {
        "input": [
          {
            "mapTo": "command",
            "type": 1,
            "value": "pathParams.command"
          }
        ],
        "output": [
          {
            "mapTo": "data",
            "type": 1,
            "value": "someResponse"
          }
        ]
      },
      "settings": {
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/trigger/:command"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I think the question is mainly, where (in which mapping scope) dies the REST input handler set the "command" property, and how do I reference it in my activity for an input Parameter.

Here are my current actions where I am trying to reference the property, but wihtout success:

"actions": [
    {
      "id": "kubectlAction",
      "name": "my kubectl action",
      "ref": "github.com/TIBCOSoftware/flogo-contrib/action/flow",
      "data": {
        "flow": {
          "name": "my kubectl flow",
          "attributes": [],
          "rootTask": {
            "id": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "tasks": [
              {
                "id": 2,
                "type": 1,
                "activityRef": "gitlab.spe.mobi/cbfr-demo/kubecontrol",
                "name": "log",
                "attributes": [],
                "inputMappings": [
                  {
                    "type": 1,
                    "value": "$property[valve-red-a]",
                    "mapTo": "yaml"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": 1,
                    "value": "$flow.command",
                    "mapTo": "command"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "links": [
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]

Any help much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should define the inputs for your flow, an the that will be used as activity input.